Send Custom Interactive Layout in iMessage Extension
I am integrating iMessage app where I have audio which I want to send as Message. But My requirement is to send a custom layout with play button on it and by tapping on it I can play/pause audio. Also On tapping on sent message view presentation style changes to expanded while I want to not have any presentation change. I just want to tap on message to play audio, nothing else.
recently I tried to make a custom layout and then by taking its screenshot I sent it as image, but issue is I cant make this view interqctive. I can play audio on tap of message but I also want to update the layout of the selected message.
here is the code I have to send message:
func sendCustomViewMessage(url:URL) {
        let customView = MessageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50)) 
        customView.audioURL = url
        let customViewImage = imageFromView(view: customView) // Convert custom view to UIImage
        
        let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
        layout.image = customViewImage // Set the image of the message layout
        layout.mediaFileURL = url
        
        let message = MSMessage()
        message.layout = layout
        message.url = url
        
        self.activeConversation?.insert(message, completionHandler: nil)
    }

& these functions to update layout but its not working:

    override func willSelect(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
        super.willSelect(message, conversation: conversation)
        if let selectedMessage = conversation.selectedMessage {
            updateMessageLayout(selectedMessage)
        }
    }
    
func updateMessageLayout(_ message: MSMessage) {
    guard let layout = message.layout as? MSMessageTemplateLayout else {
        return
    }
    
    // Update the layout as needed
    layout.caption = "Updated Caption"
    
    // Update the message with the new layout
    message.layout = layout
    reloadInputViews()
    
    // Inform the extension to update the conversation display
    requestPresentationStyle(.expanded)
}

